# Python ftplib UnicodeEncodeError when trying to upload an XML with unicode content

Tags: python, ftplib, python-unicode

I am trying to upload an XML with unicode content to a FTP server using ftplib, but getting the following exception when I try to upload the using storbinary method. The XML data is properly encoded to unicode (utf-8), I have made sure of that, I am not sure as to why storbinary is trying to encode it to 'ascii' while uploading. Can anyone please help?

```
--> 429         ftp.storbinary("STOR file.xml", xml)
    430 
    431     def run(self):

/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.pyc in storbinary(self, cmd, fp, blocksize, callback, rest)
    463             buf = fp.read(blocksize)
    464             if not buf: break
--> 465             conn.sendall(buf)
    466             if callback: callback(buf)
    467         conn.close()

/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc in meth(name, self, *args)
    222 
    223 def meth(name,self,*args):
--> 224     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    225 
    226 for _m in _socketmethods:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 3368: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: It looks like it's a `unicode` object, so it's not encoded at all.

Comment: Is `xml` a file object?  If not, use `StringIO` to create a file-like object from your xml string.

Comment: @AustinPhillips:Yes, I build the XML and use the StringIO object to pass it on to ftplib.

Comment: @Cairnarvon:  I did not understand what you meant, the string I write to the StringIO instance is an unicode instance, and just make sure about the encoding, I even tried adding a ".encode("utf-8")" to the string before writing to the StringIO object.

Comment: @asp Please provide a minimal example showing the generation of the unicode string.

Comment: @AustinPhillips, please find the code below;
Comments seems to be removing my formatting, pastebin link below;
http://pastebin.com/GugTLRQJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution, the comment by @Cairnarvon was partially correct, I was encoding the string, but there were other bits of the string written to the StringIO instance that were not encoded. Finally I ended up creating the XML bit and encoding it as a whole. You can see my code in the pastebin link below;

http://pastebin.com/GugTLRQJ

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a file opened in a binary mode to `ftp.storbinary()`. For example, if you want to upload a Unicode string as a `filename` file:

```
import io

assert isinstance(unicode_string, unicode)
file = io.BytesIO(unicode_string.encode("utf-8"))
ftp.storbinary("STOR filename", file)
```

If `unicode_string` contains xml; make sure that the character encoding used in the xml declaration is consistent with the encoding you use to store the file.

Comment: I use a StrinIO instance to pass to the storbinary method.

Comment: @asp: `StringIO` works with both Unicode strings and bytestrings in Python 2. Use `BytesIO` to make it explicit that only bytes are allowed.